# UWP NavigationView navigation via MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, navigation

I am using as main control in my app NavigationView and have Frame where page is loading.

```
<NavigationView x:Name="MyNavView" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" SelectionChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.OnSelectionChanged}" PaneDisplayMode="Top">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Contact" Content="Contact" Tag="MasterDetailPage"/>
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Favorite" Content="Favorites" Tag="FavoritesPage"/>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <Frame x:Name="RootFrame"/>
</NavigationView>
```

There are two events **SelectionChanged** and **ItemInvoked** that make available to realise navigation to pages that loading in *RootFrame* (name of my frame). But I want to use Command to make MVVM. And I have not found Command prop even for **NavigationView** itself or for **NavigationViewItem**. After that I have handled SelectionChanged event in ViewModel but at my view it contradicts MVVM.

So,how can I make MVVM using Command? If there is no such opportunity tell how to realise MVVM itself not handling event.

Comment: FWIW, it's still MVVM compliant if you handle the selection change event in your view, that simply forwards the appropriate information to a method on your ViewModel. No need to over complicate anything.

Comment: You already have your ViewModel referenced in your code-behind in order to use x:Bind, so I can't think of any reason whatsoever why you can't just use the code-behind event handlers. This does not violate MVVM, not even a little. That said, Xaml Behaviors can probably do what you want.

Comment: You are wright @SeanO'Neil ,that behavior make able what I am going to do.I made MVVM with Command using EventToCommand from [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/) nuget package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implementing this is very similar to how you do it for WPF, you need to start by installing the Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed package via NuGet. Then you add a behavior to your NavigationView:

```
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"

<NavigationView MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MenuItems}">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemInvoked">
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.ItemInvokedCommand}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

I'm using `x:Bind` here for compile-time error checking but a regular `Binding` will work just as well of course. Either way, follow this up with a command handler in your view model just as you would for WPF:

```
private ICommand _ItemInvokedCommand;
public ICommand ItemInvokedCommand => this._ItemInvokedCommand ?? (this._ItemInvokedCommand = new RelayCommand<NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs>(OnItemInvoked));


private void OnItemInvoked(NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    // could also use a converter on the command parameter if you don't like
    // the idea of passing in a NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs
    this.NavigationService.NavigateTo(args.InvokedItem);
```

Comment: This definitely works but you are not achieving any of the benefits expected from MVVM viewmodel first approach. For example, you can't really test the interactivity behavior without knowing that you are using a 'NavigationView' in the UI part. You can't plug a different UI on top of the view model.

Comment: @Addessattar true, hence why I added the comment `could also use a converter on the command parameter...`

Comment: The converter won't solve the problem of the VM knowing that it is being presented via a NavigationView control. Imho, if you want to be faithful to testability in MVVM, the root VM should be just a collection of Items, each one has a VM attached to it as well. The root VM maintains an observable `SelectedItem` property which tells the current item. The View, which is aware that it is using a NavigationView control, would simply react to the changes to that property by requesting the Frame to navigate the Page corresponding to the VM of the `SelectedItem`.

Comment: the above ofc is very subbjective. I personally believe that the VM should not know what controls are being used. I also believe that it is OK to have code behind the XAML in a View as long as it is limited to code required for the control to work properly, not code to replace the interaction logic in the VM.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [Windows Template Studio](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio), its solved my problem when combining NavigationView with MVVM

Comment: How do they solve this scenario in the template? it would be interesting if you included some more info :) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In order to see how to properly use the NavigationView control (including the Data Binding case), please refer to the companion app called **XAML Controls Gallery**, available in the Windows Store, by Microsoft.

Best regards