# Navigation in NavigationView via MVVM using Prism

Tags: c#, uwp, prism, navigationview

Prism UWP: [Prism for UWP](https://dzone.com/articles/prism-uwp-for-beginners-setup) 
NavigationView UWP: [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview)

I want to apply MVVM on my NavigationView navigation, I found this article: [navigation via mvvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944523/uwp-navigationview-navigation-via-mvvm) but Iam using Prism, so it doesnt solve my problem.

Navigation in prism:

```
using Prism.Unity.Windows;

NavigationService.Navigate("Main", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Windows Template Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WASTeamAccount.WindowsTemplateStudio) to create your project and choose the 'Navigation Pane' and 'prism Design pattern'.

Then, you will see the `_navigationService` in the `ShellViewModel` class.

You could use it for navigation.

```
_navigationService.Navigate(pageKey, null);
```

Comment: thank you for the response, but is there a way to just do this without template studio?

Comment: @NicoTing 'Windows Template Studio' also uses the same prism library in its project. The basic principle is the same. What you want to know is how to use the prism NaviagtionService in your uwp project. So, believe me, try to use 'Windows Template Studio' to create a simple code demo and check its source code to learn how to use it in your project.

Comment: I just checked it , yes it is amazing library, Thank You.